# Merge Landsat GeoTIFF files failed in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, landsat

I am working with Landsat-9 images,

I want to merge two GeoTIFF files of same band.

These are the images I want to merge.
[image]

I set the following raster -> miscellaneous->merge.
I set assign '0' as no data.

But after merge it will show like this.
[image]

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What word did you intend to use in the title that came out as "fialed"?

Comment: I have a feeling you are using incorrect files for merging. To be sure, remove all the files from QGIS, only add the 2 files that you wish to merge, then run the merge tool. If it does not work, try sharing the History of the command run (as shown in the [red box](https://postimg.cc/GBRP41YR)).